# Material UI nest drawer and appbar inside appbar with tabs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

In my app I have tabs for several files each of which should have their own drawer and appbar. The codesandbox is similar to what I'm trying to do.

https://codesandbox.io/s/wyv8m32kk7

As you can see the content of the first tab is way down beneath the drawer. How do you prevent this?

I tried adding a left margin to the content like the appbar has, but it didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is being caused by the `position: relative` on the drawer, which is interacting with `display: block` div that it's wrapped in.

To achieve this effect (of the navigation drawer being BELOW the app bar), use a Z-index and padding/margin:

```
drawerPaper: {
    zIndex: 0,
    paddingTop: 60,
    width: drawerWidth,
  },
```

Source: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/957